# Obtain an optimal solution for transportation problem

Tags: optimization, operations-research, optimal-transport

[image]

Consider Problem **8.1-1**

I did parts (a) and (b).

For (c), should I solve using either:

1. Minimum cost method and then method of multipliers?
2. Vogel method and then method of multipliers?

Is there an easier way to solve (c) (without using software)?

If so, what is it?

Comment: You can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm

Comment: Alternatively, the transport problem is in particular a linear programming problem, so you can use any algorithm for that

Comment: I had never heard of Vogel approximation method, but it seems that it doesn't provide an actual solution, just a guess. I don't understand the utility for it. Just use the Hungarian algorithm or any LP solver

Comment: Look up the Stepping Stone and Modified Distribution Methods (MODI). You can probably find simple examples like yours on Youtube. Vogel's method simply finds an initial feasible solution which may be close enough to optimal or quite often optimal. The Hungarian Method is for assignment problems, a special case of transportation problems.

Comment: @Federico Vogel approximation method is used to find the basic solution, it's 'better' than minimum cost method according to my instructor.

Comment: @Paul aha the Hungarian Method is for assignment problems, so can't I use it to solve (c) ?

Comment: MODI with stepping stone to improve a none optimal solution would be how I would do it.

Comment: Also recall that a transport problem is in particular an instance of max flow problem, so you can use any min cut/max flow algorithm

Answer (score 0):

The exercise merely asks you to find an optimal solution, so it shouldn't matter how you obtain it, as long as the method you use is correct, and reasonably efficient.

Like other commenters, I had never before come across the Vogel method for obtaining an initial basic feasible solution. While your instructor might regard it as a "better" method than the min cost method, it looks to me like it's also somewhat more complicated. So, if *I* were doing the problem I'd use either the northwest corner method or the min-cost method.  However, if you're comfortable using Vogel's method, you should by all means feel free to use it.

From a web search, it looks like what you know as the multiplier method is the same as what I know as the [primal-dual method](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9781400884179-021/pdf).  Like the Hungarian algorithm for the assignment problem, it's just an adaptation of the primal-dual simplex method which takes advantage of the special structure of the problem.  It's therefore sometimes also referred to as a "Hungarian algorithm" even though the transportation problem is a generalisation of the assignment problem.  As far as I'm aware, there's no substantially easier way of obtaining an optimal solution.